# Converting numeric to character in R changes the number

Tags: r

I am currently working with ngrams, which are stored in a data.table in a numeric format, where each word in a vocabulary is given a unique 5 digit number and a single 4-gram looks like this :

10000100001017060484

The reason for storing ngrams in this manner is that numeric objects take up much less space in R. Hence, I am working with some large numbers, which I occasionally need to convert to character and back to do some string manipulation. Today, I noticed that my Rstudio does not seem to store large numbers correctly. For example :

```
as.numeric(125124313242345145234513234432)
[1] 125124313242345143744028208602
```

As you can see, the top number is very different from bottom. The only global option I used was:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Can someone explain why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Regards,
Kamran.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers

Comment: Does that also apply to integers that are not calculated, @Dason? I understood the difference between numbers to be "somewhere after the comma/dot". Kamran seems to receive wrong numbers also for the code in below "answer", which does not perform any calcuations. But maybe I will simply have to dig deeper in R Inferno, etc. for understanding this.

Comment: UPDATE: I realized that this problem does not affect small numeric entries and integers. Subsequently, I found a package called bit64, which allows to store integers in R as 64bit, as opposed to default 32bit. This does allow for creation of large integers, but not large enough for my use.  The search continues...

Comment: UPDATE: I have managed to replicate the same issue on another laptop, with a freshly installed R and R studio. My laptop runs windows 10, the other laptop ran windows 7. I am starting to believe that this is not a problem with settings, but something to do with the numeric object class itself. I will contact R studio support to see if I can get this clarified.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `.Machine$integer.max`, it would return `2147483647` which means R can't by default would handle integer greater than `2147483647`. If you run `.Machine$double.xmax`, you would get a value of `1.797693e+308` which is the maximum double representation of floating number in R.The reasoning could be seen as exponent(308) and significand(1.797...) which are two different sets of storing the numbers.

```
?.Machine
```

http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~drh20/R/html/base/html/zMachine.html

In your case if you try to append L (way of telling R that you want to store something like an integer) in the number you will get something like this:

```
as.numeric(125124313242345145234513234432L)
[1] 1.251243e+29
Warning message:
non-integer value 125124313242345145234513234432L qualified with L; using numeric value
```

Hence you can see because of this limitations on saving integer and double in R you are getting this outcome.

To overcome this, you can convert it into a bigz using `gmp` library

```
 as.bigz("125124313242345145234513234432")
```

**Output**:

```
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 125124313242345145234513234432
```

This is my understanding about storing numbers in R, It might not be perfect but this how I see things in R for storing numbers.

You may choose to see the `gmp` documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf

Comment: Hi Kumar, this is a good suggestion. I have tried it and indeed, it does display the integer correctly. However, I am using numbers to represent words in a sequence to save RAM and a 25 digit Big Integer object takes up 280 bytes, while numeric class only uses 48.  Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for making this an answer, but its too long for a comment. What happens if you run below code. On my machine with `scipen = 999` your conversion works fine. Have you stored your numbers for the ngrams really as `numeric`? In below code you may see that a potential error might arise from converting between `character` and `numeric` depending on the settings.

```
mynumber <- 125124313242345145234513234432
options(scipen = 999)
mynumber == as.numeric(mynumber)
#[1] TRUE
mynumber == as.numeric(as.character(mynumber))
#[1] TRUE

options(scipen = 0)
mynumber == as.numeric(mynumber)
#[1] TRUE
mynumber == as.numeric(as.character(mynumber))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, thank you for the reply. I get the same results as you and I can assure you that ngrams were numeric. Incidentally, my Rstudio stores "mynumber" as 125124313242345143744028208602.

Comment: That is really strange. I will have to dig deeper into comparison of `options`. Maybe we could compare the R default `options` to yours and check where there are differences. Maybe some other option corrupts your command. I am not an expert regarding the settings, hence, I will need some time to answer. In any case it will be worth checking all options concering formatting of numbers.